# XML-to-XML conversion using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to change from one format XML to another using XSLT. I have following XML like this

```
<Class xmlns="http://www.test.com/">
<student id='1'>
<firstname>James</firstname>
<lastname>Chistoper</lastname>
<age>35</age>
<dob>08/11/1982</dob>
</student>
</Class>
```

I want to remove age and dob and also from student need to remove 'id'. final xml should be in this format,

```
<Class xmlns="http://www.test.com/">
<student>
<firstname>James</firstname>
<lastname>Chistoper</lastname>
</student>
</Class>
```

Can anyone give me suggestion to achieve it. I tried out many xslt cannot able to achieve it. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Show the XSL script you have written and indicate your specific problem with your coding.

Comment: What XSL have you written so far? Please visit the [help] and read [ask], you are expected to make an effort yourself and ask when you run into something you don't understand in your code.  If all you're trying to do is remove some elements, just write an identity transform (look it up on Wikipedia) and add empty templates for the elements you want to remove.

Comment: my xsl script is some what like this <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://www.test.com/">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t:age|t:dob"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:student/@id|a:age|a:dob" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See Transformation on http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5vz